# How to create one cell in a view and retain the value from other view?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, uitableview, return-value

I'm a begginer developer and I would like to know, how to create just one cell in a UIview and  retain the value that I obtained from another UIView.

Example:
-principalView > Here I'm going to select several values like adding an Event.
-dateTimeView > Here is a view where I select date and time (this is a second view from principalView)

In the cell in principalView when I selected date and time values, I wanna pass the value from dateTimeView to principalView (specific in the cell)

Just like this >  https://ipad.redlands.qld.edu.au/sites/ipad.redlands.qld.edu.au/files/images/Ipad_Support/Ipad_tips_and_tricks/calendar%20details.jpg

https://ipad.redlands.qld.edu.au/sites/ipad.redlands.qld.edu.au/files/images/Ipad_Support/Ipad_tips_and_tricks/calendar%20repeat.jpg

I'm Junior developer, please try to explain in a easier way.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the bottom is pretty tough! It requires doing a lot of **reading**, **googling** and **practice**. I'm not going to show you the answer. However, I will give you a nudge in the right direction.

The links that you posted were to a calendar app. The layout is basically a **UITableView**.

The calendar app quite possibly uses **NSUserDefault** for storing the user's settings. [Click here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140301073043/http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/03/08/save-data-using-nsuserdefaults-tutorial/) for a tutorial on using the NSUserDefault feature.